# Adding items into Inventory confusion

Tags: java, arrays

The Inventory consists of two arrays, one an array of objects[10] and one an array of ints[10]. The array of objects is to identify an item, and the array of ints is supposed to keep track of how many you have. For some reason the code is producing all kinds of errors. Not really sure what to do!

```
public void additem(Object newItem) {

    if (itemsInInventory == 0) {
        invent[0] = newItem;
        inventItemAmount[0]++;
        itemsInInventory++;
    }else if (itemsInInventory > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < itemsInInventory; i++) {
            if (invent[i].getItemNum() == newItem.getItemNum()) {
                inventItemAmount[i]++;
            } else {
                invent[itemsInInventory] = newItem;
                inventItemAmount[itemsInInventory]++;
                itemsInInventory++;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Complete code can be found here: https://github.com/YungSheep/HitsujiStories

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: try to implement same code with java collections i.e. there is ArrayList HashMap check how they work. They have useful methods like contains, isempty try to benefit from that

Comment: Show your stacktrace if possible or tell us which line throws any exceptions. It will be much more easier to find a bug in your code (because it is quite confusing :))

Comment: @HRgiger This is a great tool! Will check into it and see if it's easier to use. Thank you

Comment: Depending on what operation I change in the if statements, it could be a null pointer exception or displaying undesirable information such as incorrect item amounts and null items. @RiaanNel

Comment: @Uata Yes, of course I can! Just off the top of my head this is where I think the bug is: Main(Line:23) > Object(Line:109) > Flower(Line:37) > You(Line: 59). Can you tell me why the code is confusing, lack of comments.. poorly structured..etc? Just curious because I'm new to coding and showing others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see in your GitHub code that your inventory is limited to 10 ; and your if-else condition doesn't hold any case for itemsInInventory > 10, that will first give you an idea of where your NPE comes from. It might be better for you to change your current else if condition to something like "a > 0 && a <= max" then add a case when it's higher than your max capacity.

EDIT : Also, I'm pretty sure I know why you get messed up amounts for each type of item : if you imagine the if-else statement inside a loop, the item slot [0] would only be accessible once, when the player has an empty inventory. That means I can't add up any further in the slot [0] if I picked an item and set itemsInInventory to another number than 0 ! You might have to rebuild your if-else contents.

SECOND EDIT : In case you find it messy to code, I suggest you to make an InventorySlot class :

```
public class InventorySlot {
    private Object object;
    private int amount;

// CONSTRUCTOR (assuming you don't instanciate filled slots)
    public InventorySlot() {
        this.setObject(null);
        this.setAmount(0);
    }

// GETTERS AND SETTERS
    public Object getObject() {
        return this.object;
    }

    public int getAmount() {
        return this.amount;
    }

    public void setObject(final Object object) {
        this.object = object;
    }

    public void setAmount(final int amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
        }

// METHOD THAT ADDS NEW ITEM IF MATCHES. RETURNS BOOLEAN TO TELL IF SUCCEEDED
        public bool addIfMatches(final Object object) {
            if (this.getObject.getItemNum() == object.getItemNum()) {
                this.setAmount(this.getAmount++);
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

// AND OTHER USEFUL METHODS...

}
```

Hope this helps you, happy coding !

Comment: Yes, that's a great point. Any clue why it's not keeping track of the item amounts correctly?

Comment: I just noticed and edited it, no worries. Keep us updated if you get another trouble ! @BrandonFinley

Comment: Oh wow, you killed this answer. Thanks man! Appreciate you spending the time to look at this. What does this. do?

Comment: It basically allows you to regroup your two arrays into one, so now if you want to manage your inventory you only have to manage one array of InventorySlot. That way you can get the amount and the object type by doing InventorySlot[x].getObject() and InventorySlot[x].getAmount as x a variable between 0 and 9 (since your inventory has 10 slots).

Comment: The method addIfMatches will help you adding new objects into your inventory slots, since the method checks if the new object is the same as the one in the slot. If true, then it will add the item and increase the amount, but if false then it would do nothing and return a false boolean from the method. Using the boolean result, you can try it on each slot starting from 0 until you find a slot with the same item.